# Understanding quantum teleportation algorithm from qiskit tutorials

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, qiskit, teleportation

I am very new to quantum computing and I have recently started to experiment with `qiskit` module in python, by following tutorials and implementing simple algorithms.

I constructed the quantum circuit described on this page: [Qiskit teleportation](https://community.qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html) And got same results that were expected:

my circuit:

[image: Teleportation]

my results:

[image: results]

Which are apparently expected results, since

> "we will always measure 0 from Bob's qubit because we started off with
>   |0⟩"

However, if I apply NOT Gate at the start of q0, I still get the exact same results. Is my understanding of algorithm wrong? Shouldnt I be getting q2 as 1 after applying the NOT gate at start?

code:

```
import qiskit as q
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

circuit = q.QuantumCircuit(3, 3)

# entangle cubit 1 & 2

circuit.h(1)

circuit.cx(1, 2)

# apply CNOT to qubit we want to send
circuit.cx(0, 1)

circuit.h(0)

circuit.measure([0,1], [0,1])

circuit.cx(1, 2)

circuit.cz(0, 2)

print(circuit)

backend = q.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = q.execute(circuit, backend, shots=1024)
result = job.result()

counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

Outcomes when NOT gate is inserted at the start of q0:

[image]

Comment: Your circuit is good; could you insert the image of the alternative circuit? I am not sure what you did, and a picture is better than words.

Comment: @kludg, you mean circuit in Ascii? I will post that as well along with code

Comment: no, i meant the picture of alternative circuit like the picture of original circuit.

Comment: @kludg I am not sure what you mean, the picture in post is generated by `circuit.draw(output='mpl')` so it is the description of what my code is doing

Comment: possibly dumb question: you say Bob should always get 0 from the circuit befor you add your X. So, what's the ordering of the bits in the labels on your bar chart? Does Bob's bit correspond to the first bit?

Comment: @DaftWullie, First qbit is one that is supposed to be teleported, second one is Alice's qubit, third one is Bob's qubit. By the end First qubits value should be transferred to Bob's qubit (q0 to q2)

Comment: so if that's what's supposed to happen, why aren't all 4 possible outcomes ending in 0?

Comment: @DaftWullie, the labels at the bottom of histogram are reversed, reading from bottom to up, its q2, q1, q0

Comment: Can we also see the histogram for the circuit with the X in place?

Comment: @DaftWullie, will update the OP

Comment: shouldn't you measure q2 after teleportation?

Comment: @kludg, yep, that was the mistake, since that step was not explicitly mentioned in the steps, I just thought it was not necessary, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit does not measure $q_2$ qubit after teleportation; I guess that is why teleportation of $|1\rangle$ qubit is shown incorrectly.